# issue augmenting while running this query

Tags: phpmyadmin

```
CREATE TABLE `Shoutit`.`shouts` ( `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `user` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , `message` TEXT NOT NULL , `time` TIME NOT NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

when I am running this query it's showing me this error  `#1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key.`

I know that there should be one Auto incrementing field per table and that should be primary key as well.... no clue why it is showing any error....

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set a primary key to the `id` column:

```
CREATE TABLE Shoutit.shouts 
(
   `id` INT(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT , 
   `user` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
   `message` TEXT NOT NULL , 
   `time` TIME NOT NULL 
) 
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Auto-increment values need to be a primary key in mysql.